# no funciona el setOnItemClickListener de listview en Fragment

Tags: android-studio, listview

Por si acaso ya revise las "Preguntas que ya pueden tener tu respuesta" pero ninguna soluciona mi problema.

Seguir todos los pasos del tutorial donde explicaba como hacerlo pero no se porque no me funciona.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

Fragment:

```
private void loadListViewAccount(){
    ArrayList<ItemListViewAccount> listAccounts = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        listAccounts.add(new ItemListViewAccount(i, R.drawable.ic_person_grey50_20dp, "Nombre completo", "correoelectronico@outlook.com"));
    }

    ItemListViewAccountAdapter adapter = new ItemListViewAccountAdapter(getContext(), listAccounts);
    listViewAccount.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewAccount.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

ItemListViewAccountAdapter.java:

```
public class ItemListViewAccountAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<ItemListViewAccount> listaObjetos;

public ItemListViewAccountAdapter(Context context, List<ItemListViewAccount> listaObjetos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaObjetos = listaObjetos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaObjetos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listaObjetos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listaObjetos.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View viewListAccount;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    viewListAccount = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview_recover_password_account, null);

    ImageView imageViewFotoPerfil = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.imgView_FotoPerfil);
    TextView textViewNombre = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.txtViewNombre);
    TextView textViewCorreoElectronico = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.txtViewCorreoElectronico);

    imageViewFotoPerfil.setImageResource(listaObjetos.get(position).getFoto_perfil());
    textViewNombre.setText(listaObjetos.get(position).getNombre());
    textViewCorreoElectronico.setText(listaObjetos.get(position).getCorreo_electronico());

    return viewListAccount;
}
}
```

fragment_recover_password_layout2.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".Access.RecoverPassword.FragmentRecoverPasswordLayout2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_grey50_20dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/view_circle"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/tea500"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="Seleccione su cuenta"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/Grey400"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Encontramos las siguientes cuentas en base a los datos que proporcionaste."/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lstView_Account"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_listview_recover_password_account"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.75"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.5">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_Siguiente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_corners_oval_tea500"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="SIGUIENTE"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.75"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6.5">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_NingunaEsTuCuenta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="¿Ninguna es tu cuenta?"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3.5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

item_listview_recover_password_account.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rdbtnAccount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView_FotoPerfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_grey50_20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7.5"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Nombre completo"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCorreoElectronico"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:text="correoelectronico@outlook.com"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Y la lista que se carga perfectamente el problema es que no aparece el Toast cuando hago click en uno de los items del ListView, sera que es por lo que lo estoy haciendo en un fragment?

Comment: es un listview?

Comment: si, en el titulo dice listview

Comment: en tu xml tienes algun otro elemento con requesfocus?

Comment: agregue los xml correspondientes, y requestfocus no.

Comment: prueba con getActivity().getApplicationContext() el lugar del get contect del onclick

Comment: ya lo hize, no funciona.

Comment: algun error en el logCat?

Comment: ya lo revise, y no, nada, ningun error.

Comment: ya encontre el problema, era el radiobutton que le puse al item, nose porque eso impedia el evento del click, pero lo quite y funciona. Deberia eliminar esta pregunta?.

Comment: intenta colocando `android:focusable="false"` a tu radio button

Answer (score 0):

Habilita la propiedad `setClickable(true)`:

```
 ...
  listView.setClickable(true);

  listViewAccount.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   ...
```

Esto habilitara que pueda realizar una acción al recibir un clic.